# How to fix windows 10 wi-fi unaccesibility after update

Tags: windows, wireless-networking

after updating my windows 10 , I can not access to my Wi-Fi I use [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3084164) and [this](http://www.redmondpie.com/fix-no-wi-fi-available-after-windows-10-upgrade-issue-heres-how/). But It  told me "ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value."

By the way, I do not upgrade from win 8 to win 10. I just updated win 10.

Comment: I assume you have manually verified that key does not exist?